# Can't connect to API using React.js fetch method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to connect to buffer's API (https://buffer.com/developers/api/oauth) via react.js using `fetch()`, but I'm getting a 400 error response.

This is running on my localhost but the site's accessible from the Internet.

Here's my code:

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
        const parsed = queryString.parse(window.location.search);

const buffer_data = {
                client_id: BUFFER_CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: BUFFER_CLIENT_SECRET,
                redirect_uri: BUFFER_CALLBACK_URL,
                code: parsed.code,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code',
};

fetch(BUFFER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, {
                method: 'post',
                body: JSON.stringify(buffer_data),
              }).then( data => {
                console.log('data response ' + data);
                return data.json();
            }).then( response => {
                console.log(response);
});
```

And here's the response:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type
> parameter or parameter missing"}

And the console prints this:

> Failed to load https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. Origin 'http://myserver.com' is therefore not allowed
> access. The response had HTTP status code 400. If an opaque response
> serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
> resource with CORS disabled.

I've tried lots of things, like not serializing the data, trying sending many different headers, using a CORS chrome plugin, etc

Before coding this in react, I've successfully connected using PHP, but to do that I had to add an SSL certificate on my server.

I'm also open to use any library but haven't found one to do this job. Or any other fetching method, like `axios`?

Comment: Just tried, didn’t work either

Comment: The 400 error you’re getting back in the only problem you need to fix. You don’t have a CORS problem. A 400 means Bad Request — it’s the server indicating that the request it received in not in the format it expects or can handle. The server by default only adds the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 2xx success responses, not to 4xx or 5xx errors.

Comment: Ok. The parameters sent are exactly what is needed, since it worked in PHP. I guess they’re being sent in the wrong format, but already tried sending it as json, stringified and as var1=value&var2=value and didn’t work either. So don’t know what the hell im doing wrong, any guess?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? And setting the`grant_type` like so `grant_type=${authorization_code}&code=$parsed.code}&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}`?

Comment: Didn't work either. Temporarily worked around the problem using a cors plugin for chrome, but I'm still looking for a permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

Try adding headers

```
    fetch(BUFFER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                         },
                body: JSON.stringify(buffer_data),
              }).then( data => {
                console.log('data response ' + data);
                return data.json();
            }).then( response => {
                console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which browser you are using, but you might want to add [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

for your chrome browser (if you are using chrome). This is some issue that seems to occur when you are using localhost with chrome.

Also, i highly recommend using axios for fetching API's, it comes with some easy error logs that can help you pinning down the issue pretty fast.

Greetings!

Comment: Tried that also, didn’t work. I’m using chrome. Would you mind sharing how this would look with axios?

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-chrome-sample/issues/11 out? axios is absoluetely simple, you always call the different api points with axios.get, axios.put, axios.update etc. etc. and update the class state via setState. There is a lot of good documentation out there.